# nearest neighbor 2 dimensions

Tags: nearest-neighbor

Given a set S of points in 2-dimensional space, provide an algorithm that computes nearest neighbor(euclidian) for each point in the set. I think its called nearest neighbor graph, isn't it? Any existing efficient algorithm (N log N), where N = len(S)?

Comment: looking at delaunay triangulation right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [kd-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree) is a pretty standard algorithm for nearest neighbor search (even in 2-space, don't let the first illustration throw you).